# Dancers font is squished

Tags: fonts

I want to typeset a few secret codes and I thought it would be cool to use the code in "The Dancing Men" by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle.  Sure enough, someone (Alan Stanier to be precise) created a `dancers` font in Metafont and it's included in TeXLive 2011 (OS X 10.6.8, using AUCTeX).  I tried to use it but the output is all smooshed together.  Since I know *very little* about using fonts in LaTeX I don't know if this is a problem with the font or with my usage of it.  I tried

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{
    <->  gen * dancers
}{}

\begin{document}

\usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

\end{document}
```

which produces [image: squished dancers].  Also putting `\qquad` between characters does not create a discernible difference, so I can't even work around it in that way.  I also tried deleting the file `/Users/gvol/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/dancers/dancers12.56pk` in case I had generated it incorrectly in one of my initial experiments, but it didn't help.

Adding `\fontsize{52pt}{14pt}\selectfont` after the `\usefont` gives roughly what I want, but that seems completely wrong and when selecting from the pdf it's far too large (because it's a 52pt font obviously).

What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set

```
\spaceskip=10pt
```

to get larger space between words (spaces). In this font, the interword space is 0pt, and `1em` (length of `\quad`) is also 0pt. So the spacing is too small.

You can also set

```
\fontdimen6\font=20pt
```

to get a wide `\quad`.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that the interword space is 0pt since word breaks in the code are indicated by a flag (a capital letter in the font).  Your answer allows me enough to work around the problem, but when I remove the spaces between characters they are still too close together.  At least I know that it's not something I did incorrectly.